# Trying to update a column in database but NOT NULL attributes are not letting me update the values. I am using Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to update the column with some other data but database table is not letting me update the table because of the NOT NULL constraints in it. I have this option of setting all the fields to NULL but I dont think that will be a good practice. Please I need a solution to it if anyone can help. I get the following error

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (HY000)
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'first_name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`subject_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, 2019-07-30 13:46:42, 2019-07-30 13:46:42))
>   Previous exceptions
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'first_name' doesn't have a default value (HY000)`

I have tried setting all the values to NULL and it worked but I want to work with some fields setting as NOT NULL and update the ones which are NULL and also if we can fetch or set the fields automatically to what we have ?

This is my controller where I am trying to update the field if this is required or help you understand my problem

```
public function deleteSubject($id) {

        echo $id;
        // die();
        if(Auth::check()) {

            $findSubject = Auth::user()->where('subject_id', $id);

            $users = new User();
            $users->subject_id = null;

            $users->save();
            // echo($findSubject);
            // die();

            Session::flash("message", "You subject has been deleted. You can add a new Subject now.");
            return redirect('/subjects');

        } else {
            Session::flash("message", "Please sign in to access this page");
            return redirect('/signup');
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your SQL error is telling you that you cannot insert a new record and ignore adding a value for `first_name` because if you insert nothing in it, your SQL engine wouldn't know what to put in `first_name` in the new record because there's no `default` value to put if you insert nothing.

Comment: You are creating a new instance of the `User` object after finding, it is alwasys gonna insert instead of update. Use the same instance of `user` from `$findSubject = Auth::user()->where('subject_id', $id);` to update

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Oh yes you are right agam I was creating the new instance, didnt notice that. I just tried setting that to `null` by doing `$findSubject->subject_id = null;
     
            $findSubject->save();` but now getting an error of `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::save()` and this `$findSubject = Auth::user()->where('subject_id', $id);` is getting whole record where I just need to update the `subject_id`

Comment: got it fixed, Thank you for the help. I was using `get` instead of `first` which was returning a collection

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for your code. As it was said in the previous comment, it's because you try to create a new instance of a user without inserting value.

It look like you are trying to delete the subject associate with the authenticated user, so I suppose that you don't really need to create a new user, instead I think you should dissociate the user and the subject. So, the following should work for your code.

The purpose of that variant is to take the authenticated user and put a null value for the subject_id.

```
public function deleteSubject($id) {

    echo $id;
    // die();
    if(Auth::check()) {

        $user = User::where('subject_id', $id)->first(); // This will get the user that have the subect_id, but it's assuming that only one user have this subject_id.
        // You can also do this just uncomment the first line below and comment the other one above.
        // $user = User::find(Auth::user->id);
        $user->subject_id = null;
        $user->save()

        Session::flash("message", "You subject has been deleted. You can add a new Subject now.");
        return redirect('/subjects');

    } else {
        Session::flash("message", "Please sign in to access this page");
        return redirect('/signup');
    }

}
```

I think that you should take a look about how MVC work.
https://selftaughtcoders.com/from-idea-to-launch/lesson-17/laravel-5-mvc-application-in-10-minutes/

You should also take a look at relationship in Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

MVC and Eloquent-Relationships will help you understand some function in laravel to achieve this kind of goal really quickly.
If you get a User model and a Subject model, you can simply do something like this:

```
$user = User->find(Auth::user()->id);
$user->subjects()->dissociate($id);
```

I'm not sure, but I think the Auth facade let you use the user model function, so maybe this could work to:

```
Auth::user()->subjects()->dissociate($id);
```

You should also take a look at middleware: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware
With middleware, you can put rules like the one you are using to send a message to the user saying that he/she need to be log in to access the page into the middleware and reusing it whenever you need.